# Showing label next to MKPolyline

Tags: ios, uikit, mkmapview, mapkit, mkpolyline

I am trying to present a route on my MKMapView using the new iOS7 APIs for MKDirections. I have figured out how to calculate the routes and display them on the map using MKPolyline and MKPolylineRenderer. The only problem is how to display a little label next to the polylines to mark out the route's "name" as returned in the response object. For e.g. in the Maps app if you search for directions to a destination, it gives you 2 or 3 possible routes, and each has the estimated time in a little callout bubble next to them. That label / button / view is what I would like to be able to draw, ideally next to to their polylines. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.